# SSIS script task error retrieving variable values

Tags: ssis

In a `Script Task`, I am trying to retrieve a file from a networked location and `FTP` that file to an offsite location

- In SSIS I created the `FTP Connection` and tested that it is setup and works
- Created three variables

  - variable 1. FullPathName = \ftpservercsc\\\Filename.txt
  - variable 2 FTPFilePath = \ftpservercsc\\\
  - variable 3 FTPFileName = Filename.txt
- Created a `Script Task` and added the vb code as such ...

  ```
  'Get instance of the connection manager.
  Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("FTP Connection Manager")
  Dim remotePath As String = Dts.Variables("FTPFilePath").Value.ToString

  'create the FTP object that sends the files and pass it the connection
  'created above.
  Dim ftp As FtpClientConnection = New FtpClientConnection
                                          (cm.AcquireConnection(Nothing))

  'Connect to the ftp server
  ftp.Connect()

  'Set the path on the FTP server where dropping files
  'ftp.SetWorkingDirectory("/Prequalify") 'set the remote directory

  Dim files(0) As String
  files(0) = Dts.Variables("FTPFileName").Value.ToString 'eg. File1.trg

  'Send File
  ftp.SendFiles(files, remotePath, True, True)

  ' Close the ftp connection
  ftp.Close()


  'Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, context, "File " + fileToGet 
  '     + " retrieved successfully.", Nothing, Nothing, True)
  Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
  ```
- Error: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

So I have commented out and found the error is generating on retrieving the variable value but I do not know what is incorrect here

```
    Dim remotePath As String = Dts.Variables("FTPFilePath").Value.ToString
```

I have tried multiple variable retrievals and all get the same error. Anyone see anything wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure you config the Script Task to have Read Access to the variable.  To do this right-click on the Script Task and select Edit.  Click the ... under ReadOnlyVariables.
2. Fully qualify your variables such as `Dts.Variables["User::RemotePath"].Value`

Comment: Excellent! That was exactly it. The script runs now however it doesnt actually copy the file over. I think this gave me a great start though. Thanks for the assistance.